# Regex: how to separate username:password?

Tags: regex

Regex: how to separate username:password?
I need a code to separate in 2 diferrent lists usernames and passowrds

```
john:123
place:Abc457
```

etc.

Final lists:

```
john
place
```

etc.

and 2'nd list.txt

```
123
Abc457
```

etc.

Well I prefer more the passwords and not necessarily the usernames, Thanks

Comment: What **language**? Why use regex? Just **split** on `:` ...

Comment: What language? Why not just use a text-splitting function?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Why is this question even being asked on SO? Thousands of answers for syntax and usage on the www.. this isn't a problem. Off-topic I assume? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would use `(.*?):(.*)`. Then you can access the username as group 1 (`$1` in substitutions) and the password as group 2.

To create your first textfile use `$1` ( http://regexr.com/3b8as )

```
john
place
```

To create your second textfile use `$2` ( http://regexr.com/3b8av )

```
123
Abc457
```

Comment: @MunteanCosminManim I updated my answer (see also the links to the examples). Is it now working?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the usernames per your non-need of it, but it'd be trivial to modify the following examples to keep it. Below examples show regex extract and split operations for both Python and Perl.

Python regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "john:123"
>>> pw = []
>>> pw.append(re.match(r'.*?:(.*)', s).group(1))
>>> pw
['123']
```

Perl regex:

```
my $s = "john:123";
my @a;

$s =~ /.*?:(.*)/;
push @a, $1 if $1;

print @a;
```

Python split:

```
>>> s = "john:123"
>>> pw = []
>>> pw.append(s.split(':')[1])
>>> pw
['123']
```

Perl split:

```
my $s = "john:123";
my @a;

push @a, (split(/:/, $s))[1];

print @a;
```